# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Style'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with 'style = ttk.Style()', it seems to not accept style as an attribute. I'm not sure why.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import IntVar

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("main", background="blue")
```

Expected results: all labels and buttons using the defined style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to import tkinter as ttk, delete the second line.

and use style like this:
style = Style()

your code would finally be:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import IntVar

style = Style()

style.configure("main", background="blue")
```